# sqlite3 error: You did not supply a value for binding 1

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

```py
def save():
    global editor
    conn = sqlite3.connect('address_book.db')

    c = conn.cursor()

    recordID = delete_box.get()

    c.execute("""UPDATE addresses SET
                first_name=:first,
                last_name=:last,
                address=:address,
                city=:city,
                state=:state,
                zipcode=:zipcode

                WHERE oid=:oid""",
                {
                'oid': int(recordID),
                'first:': ef_name.get(),
                'last': el_name.get(),
                'address': eaddress.get(),
                'city': ecity.get(),
                'state': estate.get(),
                'zipcode': ezipcode.get()})

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    editor.destroy()
```

> File "C:/Users/Luke/PycharmProjects/GUI/database.py", line 23, in save
>       c.execute("""UPDATE addresses SET
>   sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 1.

Can anybody see what is causing this error? I'm sure that I didn't make a typo anywhere and am very confused what could be the root of this.

Comment: Look at your colons again.

Comment: @Shawn could you clarify please?

Comment: @Shawn sorry, this is my first time using sqlite3, so I checked again and am still lost

Comment: One entry in your dict of parameter bindings is not like the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! I think the error you made is that you have used the parameter subtitution style ([paramstyle](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)) that is not the default one on `sqlite3`. You are trying to use the `named` style instead of the default `qmark` style. If you used the `qmark` style your `UPDATE` would have looked like this:

```py
c.execute(
    'UPDATE addresses SET first_name=?, last_name=?, address=?, city=?, state=?, zipcode=? WHERE old=?', 
    (ef_name.get(), el_name.get(), eaddress.get(), ecity.get(), 
     estate.get(), ezipcode.get(), int(recordID))
)
```

But if you really want to use the `named` paramstyle, you can set that attribute for that module. Here's a complete example:

```py
import sqlite3

sqlite3.paramstyle = 'named'

parameters = [
    {
        'old': 1,
        'first': "Tony",
        'last': "Starks",
        'address': '10880 Malibu Point',
        'city': 'Malibu',
        'state': 'California',
        'zipcode': '12345-6789'
    },
    {
        'old': 1,
        'first': "Pepper",
        'last': "Potts",
        'address': '10880 Malibu Point',
        'city': 'Malibu',
        'state': 'California',
        'zipcode': '12345-6789'
    }
]


conn = sqlite3.connect('address_book.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('CREATE TABLE addresses (old, first_name, last_name, address, city, state, zipcode)')
c.execute('INSERT INTO addresses  VALUES (:old, :first, :last, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode)', parameters[0])
conn.commit()

print('After INSERT')
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM addresses'):
    print(row)

c.execute('UPDATE addresses SET first_name=:first, last_name=:last, address=:address, city=:city, state=:state, zipcode=:zipcode WHERE old=:old', parameters[1])
conn.commit()

print('After UPDATE')
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM addresses'):
    print(row)

conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The tutorial I was watching for that section used the named paramstyle and it worked for them, so they must've either changed the paramstyle off camera or before filming. I thought I was going crazy because I ended up copying it letter for letter and it still didn't work!

Comment: You didn't explain that binding 1 is oid and the value is missing. The error message of sqlite3 is not very helpful and i think it's a bug that it only goes by number and not by name.

Comment: @Wolfgang: Like I said in my explanation, `sqlite3` seems to use by default the the `qmark` where you provide the values used by the SQL query using a tuple. Since the parameters in the SQL query are matched in the order they appear in the tuple, the error message makes totally sense since `sqlite` can only identify the parameters by their index in the tuple.

Comment: @Wolfgang: Since it looked like Luke Gries seemed to want to use the `named` style for parameters substitution, the solution was to set that value in the appropriate global variable in that module (`sqlite3.paramstyle = 'named'`). He can then use the form `old=:old` in the query and use a `dict` instead of a `tuple` to provide it the values.

Comment: Can anybody see what is causing this error?  has two causes: a principal one which you explained and a concrete one which needs to explain which column is the problem. To explain the cause its better to go by name even if the software can only handle numbers.

Comment: @Wolgang Fahl: We could say that the error is that there isn't a lot of documentation explaining how this works. But it is not better to go by name or by number. It is a choice that you can make if you prefer one way or another. That's why in the solution I have provided, I have show shown how to either run the query in `qmark` style or run it in `named` style. You can choose whatever pleases you. And I don't think you should force others to use it the way you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to the extra colon. Replace

```
'first:': ef_name.get(),
```

with

```
'first': ef_name.get(),
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the situation reported as https://bugs.python.org/issue41638 i am using a wrapper. See also [python sqlite insert named parameters or null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169642/python-sqlite-insert-named-parameters-or-null) for the solution of the more general problem on how to store dicts with different sets of keys which need to be mapped to different colums.

```
def testBindingError(self):
        '''
        test list of Records with incomplete record leading to
        "You did not supply a value for binding 2"
        see https://bugs.python.org/issue41638
        '''
        listOfRecords=[{'name':'Pikachu', 'type':'Electric'},{'name':'Raichu' }]
        for executeMany in [True,False]:
            try:
                self.checkListOfRecords(listOfRecords,'Pokemon','name',executeMany=executeMany)
                self.fail("There should be an exception")
            except Exception as ex:
                if self.debug:
                    print(str(ex))
                self.assertTrue('no value supplied for column' in str(ex))
```

which leads to:

executeMany:

```
INSERT INTO Pokemon (name,type) values (:name,:type)
failed: no value supplied for column 'type'
```

no executeMany:

```
INSERT INTO Pokemon (name,type) values (:name,:type)
failed: no value supplied for column 'type'
record  #2={'name': 'Raichu'}
```

The wrapper code is:

```
def store(self,listOfRecords,entityInfo,executeMany=False):
        '''
        store the given list of records based on the given entityInfo
        
        Args:
          
           listOfRecords(list): the list of Dicts to be stored
           entityInfo(EntityInfo): the meta data to be used for storing
        '''
        insertCmd=entityInfo.insertCmd
        try:
            if executeMany:
                self.c.executemany(insertCmd,listOfRecords)
            else:
                index=0
                for record in listOfRecords:
                    index+=1
                    self.c.execute(insertCmd,record)
            self.c.commit()
        except sqlite3.ProgrammingError as pe:
            msg=pe.args[0]
            if "You did not supply a value for binding" in msg:
                columnIndex=int(re.findall(r'\d+',msg)[0])
                columnName=list(entityInfo.typeMap.keys())[columnIndex-1]
                debugInfo=""
                if not executeMany:
                    if self.errorDebug:
                        debugInfo="\nrecord  #%d=%s" % (index,repr(record))
                raise Exception("%s\nfailed: no value supplied for column '%s'%s" % (insertCmd,columnName,debugInfo))
            else:
                raise pe
```

for more details see [storage/sql.py](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/DgraphAndWeaviateTest/blob/master/storage/sql.py) and [tests/testSqlite3.py](https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/DgraphAndWeaviateTest/blob/master/tests/testSqlite3.py)