# How to fix this error : sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 5

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I supplied all the values, but I get this Error !!! Why?
I tried some ways but none of them worked for me ...

here is the code :

```py
import sqlite3
from datetime import date
mydb=sqlite3.connect("library.db")
mycursor=mydb.cursor()


def Borrow():
    try:
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO BookBorrowReturnRecords VALUES(:Borrowers_ID,:book_ID,:bktitle,:releaseDate ,:duedate,:bkdatereturn)",
      {
        'Borrowers_ID' : BorrowersID,
        'book_ID' :bookID, 
        'bktitle' :bk_title,  
        'releaseDate' :date.today(), 
        'duedate DATE':dueDATE, 
        'bkdatereturn': no
        })
        print (f"Data added succesfully !\nYou can have book : {bk_title} till {dueDATE}...\n Make sure you keep it clean and return it like you borrow it  .... ")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print("Oooops ! Something Went wrong ....")

mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

an I get this Error :

```
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 5.
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: @Rae check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61788055/sqlite3-error-you-did-not-supply-a-value-for-binding-1#63592114

Comment: Change `'duedate DATE'` to `'duedate'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binding 5 value is 'duedate'
and your params dict about that is:

```
{'duedate DATE':dueDATE,}
```

what about the following?

```
{'duedate':dueDATE, }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with

```
'bkdatereturn': no
```

There is no such variable with name "no" defined. Are trying to insert a string "no" there?

then, as far as I know, it should be written something like this

```
    'bkdatereturn': 'no'
```